# how to add users to a favorites list with an isFav boolean?

Tags: java, list, favorites

I have a list of users and I want to add the favorite users to a list of favorites using an isFav boolean that I passed in the model user parameter, but I don't know how to go about it

in my Api :

```
@Override
    public List<Neighbour> getFavoriteNeighbours() {
        List<Neighbour> favoriteNeighbours = new ArrayList<>();
        ???
        }
        return favoriteNeighbours;
    }

@Override
    public void deleteFavoriteNeighbour(Neighbour neighbour) {
        ???
    }

    @Override
    public void addFavoriteNeighbour(Neighbour neighbour) {
        ???
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to use loops, lists, if-statements and methods? If so, what did you try and what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Another question: where should this `isFav` flag be located? On the one that has favorite neighbors? If so, what if he has more than one? If you'd put it on the neighbor, what if that neighbor is not everyone's favorite? If you'd do that on paper, how would you write down who is whose favorite neighbor?

Comment: What do you know about a `Neighbour`'s state if you have a list of favorites? Yes, you could check if a specific `Neighbour` is in that list or not.

Comment: Smells like school work

Comment: @Thomas this isfav is a neighbor parameter, either true or false. in fact I have a list of neighbors, and by clicking on a favorite fab we must be able to add the neighbors we want to a list of favorite neighbors which will be displayed in the second tab. knowing that we already have a first list of neighbors and that it is from this list that the neighbors are filtered to the list of favorites

Comment: "this isfav is a neighbor parameter" - I'd not put it into `Neighbor` but use a separate class that contains a `Neighbor` and that flag. Then iterate over the list of those objects, check the flag and if it is true add the neighbor to the favorites list.